# jQuery find not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
        <p class="first">blah blah <a href="" class="more">read more</a></p>
        <div class="read_more">
            <p>more text</p>
        </div>
```

And javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.more').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.read_more').slideDown();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Doesn't seem to do anything (read_more is set to display: none) any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery find does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494424/jquery-find-does-not-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

<strike>$(document).ready(function(){
      $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().find('.read_more').slideDown();
        return false;
      });
    });</strike>

**Update:**

**[Here is the demo :)](http://jsbin.com/iraqu4)**

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.more').click(function(){
    $(this).parents().find('.read_more').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

You could also do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.more').click(function(){
    $('.read_more').slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Or this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.more').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown('slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: You're asking it to find .read_more INSIDE your anchor tag -- and its not there. This solution fixes that for you.

Answer (score 3):

`.find(..)` looks for the selector inside the current element.

What you might want is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.more').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.read_more').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Edit

Added another `.parent()` as the `<a>` is inside `<p>` and `.read_more` is not in the `<p>`

Answer (score 2):

One potential cause of find() not being able to work is that the element you are looking for hasn't loaded when you call it.

In my case, I was replacing a text field with an editor plugin, and the editor had not loaded by the time I called find().

If you can't find the element when you know you should be able to, try setTimeout to add a delay before calling find().

*Note*: setTimeout is not a good solution for this issue, it just helps diagnose the problem. Try to come up with a way to wait until the element has loaded before you make your find() call.

Comment: Thanks for answering almost 7 years later, where were you when I needed you in 2010? :-p

Comment: Was just starting school, I knew nothing lol. Just hoping my answer might help someone else who is stuck on this.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to find .read_more under a tag in which it does not exist
by replacing the *this* with *document* it may work

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example adding a code snippet might help.