# jQuery find does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, find

I have a DocumentFragment stored in "selectedContents", and I am trying to find "span" elements in it, with the help of jQuery. It has two child nodes, where the first one is a text node, and the second one a span.

When I try `$(selectedContents.childNodes).find('span')`, it returns an empty set!

However, when I print the `"$(selectedContents.childNodes)[1].localName"` it says "span"!

Is there anything wrong in my find? Please help.

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you're passing a collection of elements, you need to use `.filter()` to filter the `<span>` out of the set.

```
$(selectedContents.childNodes).filter('span');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/

The `.find()` method is used to search for *descendants*.

---

**EDIT:** Note that your approach of passing the `childNodes` into the jQuery object is correct. You can't pass a `documentFragment` as some suggest.

**Here's an example to illustrate:** http://jsfiddle.net/P8nur/

Answer (score 2):

With `$(selectedContents.childNodes)` you already selected all elements from the `selectedContents`. So doing a find would execute the method on the first element of that selector.

Try this one:

```
$(selectedContents).find('span')
```

Comment: You'll get unexpected results pasing a `documentFragment` into a jQuery object. (It seems like it should work, but it doesn't.) You need to pass its `childNodes` like OP is doing.

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is `$(selectedContents)` return a jQuery magic thing while `$(selectedContents.childNodes)` return something like an ugly array. So, no `find()` function for your array.

Use `$(selectedContents).find('span')` or `$(selectedContents.childNodes).filter('span')`, as @justkt and @patrick dw said.

Comment: Wrong.  `$(selectedContents.childNodes)` is also a jQuery object.

Comment: You can't pass a fragment into a jQuery object. It is, however, supported to pass an array of elements like OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
$(selectedContents).find('span');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `$(selectedContents).find('span')`, but it resulted an empty set! As well as the `filter`, which too resulted empty set!

However `$(selectedContents).children('span')` resulted what I wanted!

Like patrick_dw said, probably jQuery does not work as expected with DocumentFragment!

Thanks all, for your help.

Comment: Srikanth Vittal - Instead of posting an answer, you should post a comment below someone's answer, or below your question. With regard to your code above, I'd go back to doing `$(selectedContents.childNodes)` since it is fully supported. If jQuery decides to start supporting a fragment as an argument, your code above will break. (And don't forget to click the checkmark next to an answer to "Accept" it.) :o)

Comment: Oh! I am pretty new to StackOverflow, next time I will post the comment accordingly.

By the way, do you mean I should try the find with $(selectedContents.childNodes)? Like I said in my original post, $(selectedContents.childNodes).find('span') did not work!